# What type of piano was used in the intro of this song?

Tags: piano, digital-piano, vst, texture

I'm listening to this music for about a couple of months. But I can't find a piano with similar texture and fullness.
It will be better if some can tell me where can I find a VST piano which sounds close to this piano.

Also Please provide the piano chords too. It'll help. Thank you so much.

**Link to song:**

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Actually I'm a developer. So I'm used to asking these kind of questions on stackoverflow. Anyway sorry about that man! I'll try my best to maintain the community rules.

Comment: Both questions fall foul of this site's remit, for reasons given on the help section.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like 2 sounds stacked on each other. The base sounds like a very mellow grand piano, while the upper portion could be a rhodes or a synth pad.